# How to allow assignment of incompatible Typescript types?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm sharing type definitions between my server and front-end. They're defined in a separate npm package that both install. On the front-end, variables holding ObjectIds need to be typed as that but, on the client, I can assume they're always primitive strings.

I've got a number of places on the client that throw:

```
Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

What's the easiest way to deal with this error? Can I tell Typescript to accept string assignment to ObjectId and vice versa on the client? Should I be trying to override the Mongoose definition of ObjectId?

I'm considering an override of the sort

```
declare global {
    export interface MyInterface1 {
        variableWithObjectId1: string
    }
    export interface MyInterface2 {
        variableWithObjectId2: string
    }
}
```

I think this is supposed to work. It's the recommended solution for a [similar issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/23976) but I have yet to make that work.

I'm hoping there is some way to globally transform ObjectId to string when the library is imported into the client.

Comment: What is the `ObjectId` type?

Comment: Mongo though the definition is coming via Mongoose

Comment: What about `myId: ObjectId | string` inside your interface definition.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - that solution throughs errors on the server when you want to use Mongo ObiectId methods

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId and String are not the same types at all, hence you cannot simply assign from one to the other.

You need to perform proper conversions.

Comment: If I can be absolutely sure that they're strings, what's the easiest way to do the conversion? (On the client, not in the external library where they're defined)

Comment: Update your question with research you've done for this question.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=palemoon&q=node+convert+objectid+string&ia=web

Answer (score 0):

For each of these errors on the client, I'm converting the type to a string like

```
var stringId = (myVariable as unknown) as string
```

I wish there was a cleaner way than this so I'm all ears if someone has a suggestion.